# I have to click twice on the button the see my dropdown list. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, fetch

In the following example below, I have to click twice on the "Action" button the see my dropdown list. Why? Is it possible to resolve?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".actionButton").click(function() {
    $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
    $(this).after($dropdown);
    $(this).dropdown();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td> Line 1 </td>
    <td class="dropdown"><a class="btn btn-default actionButton" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Action </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="payLink" value="App">App</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="payLink" value="Send">Send</a></li>
</ul>
```

Additional client-side logic. I upload this html on my server-side and then send it back as a response.

```
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

    async getHtml() {
    let response = await fetch('/list', {
    method: 'POST', 
           headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
    body: JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json());
  
   if (response.ok) {
     return response.data;  // the html above
    } else {
        throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
    }}
```

Comment: Converted your code to a snippet and it appears to work fine.  Please update the snippet to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: In the snippet it works fine. Check your browser developer console, maybe there is an error which might give you some hint.

Comment: @guyaloni Hi! I provided some addotinal client-side logic to see the way I am using this html. 
I can confirm that it wroks fine independantly. But it still takes two clicks to see that dropdown based on my use case.

Comment: I see, you are calling `view.getHtml()`. But I don't see `view` object in your client side code. Can you please add that as well?

Comment: @Battle Hawk Hi! I am pretty sure the view object is not related to this issue at all. It is simply used to call that getHtml method. 
I think that something is wrong when I use that html as a module. Bootstrap lib wasn't loaded on the 1st load?! JQuery?! Not sure what's actually wrong :)

Comment: @EvgeniySharahov If I do not see the full picture of your issue, then I am more lost about the issue than you are. In that case, I can only give you a suggestion that you inspect and check the console when you click. Like

```$(".actionButton").click(function() { console.log($(this), $("#contextMenu")); });```

And see when you first click, what does the console.log say in inspect?

Comment: @Battle Hawk Hi! https://prnt.sc/11jrumm   Each time I click on the button, I log proper output in the console. But the dropdown wasn't shown when I refreshed the page. Something is wrong with that bootstrap dropdown I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood so far, I think of two possible methods to get it around.

**First method:**

I suggest, you load following HTML code sample in your `#app` Element from ajax. In this way, you do not need to use onclick event on `$(".actionButton")` for this. Because according to [bootstrap3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns), you do not need set any onlclick event for loading the dropdown, it'll be done by bootstrap3 itself.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td> Line 1 </td>
    <td class="dropdown-td">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#" class="payLink" value="App">App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="payLink" value="Send">Send</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Second method:**

If above way do not work, then you have to add `bootstrap.min.css` to `<head>` tag and `jquery.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js` at end of the `<body>` tag in the main html file where  `#app` element resides in.

Then you would have to get the only barebone html from ajax and insert it into `#app`.

The barebone html code can be like below:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td> Line 1 </td>
    <td class="dropdown"><a class="btn btn-default actionButton" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Action </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="payLink" value="App">App</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="payLink" value="Send">Send</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in this case, your js code for onclick event should be like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#app").on("click", ".actionButton", function() {
    $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
    $(this).after($dropdown);
    $(this).dropdown();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! I did the following "jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min.js at end of the <body> tag in the main html file where #app element resides in" it solved the problem!

Comment: @EvgeniySharahov I am glad that one of the methods helped you resolve the problem. Happy coding and stay safe.